# Can I make this code a bit smaller?

Tags: vb.net

I have created this code to see how many text boxes have something inputted in it and then to display the total in a message box, I want to know if I can make my below code any smaller by may putting it in a loop?

```
Dim TotalRooms = 0

If String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtRoom1.Text) Then
    TotalRooms = TotalRooms + 0
Else
    TotalRooms = TotalRooms + 1
End If
If String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtRoom2.Text) Then
    TotalRooms = TotalRooms + 0
Else
    TotalRooms = TotalRooms + 1
End If
If String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtRoom3.Text) Then
    TotalRooms = TotalRooms + 0
Else
    TotalRooms = TotalRooms + 1
End If
If String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtRoom4.Text) Then
    TotalRooms = TotalRooms + 0
Else
    TotalRooms = TotalRooms + 1
End If
If String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtRoom5.Text) Then
    TotalRooms = TotalRooms + 0
Else
    TotalRooms = TotalRooms + 1
End If
If String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtRoom6.Text) Then
    TotalRooms = TotalRooms + 0
Else
    TotalRooms = TotalRooms + 1
End If
If String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtRoom7.Text) Then
    TotalRooms = TotalRooms + 0
Else
    TotalRooms = TotalRooms + 1
End If
If String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtRoom8.Text) Then
    TotalRooms = TotalRooms + 0
Else
    TotalRooms = TotalRooms + 1
End If
If String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtRoom9.Text) Then
    TotalRooms = TotalRooms + 0
Else
    TotalRooms = TotalRooms + 1
End If
If String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtRoom10.Text) Then
    TotalRooms = TotalRooms + 0
Else
    TotalRooms = TotalRooms + 1
End If


MessageBox.Show(TotalRooms)
```

Comment: Yes, you can simplify it greatly, but...... When/Where are you executing this code? Which event? Keydown? KeyPress? Mouseleave? or a seperate button? I ask because it makes a difference in how to answer.

Comment: Shouldn't this be an issue for code review?

Answer (score 0):

You can shave half of the code by removing the condition if `String.IsNullOrEmpty(Text)` since you are only incrementing `TotalRooms` otherwise.

```
If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtRoomX.Text) Then
    TotalRooms += 1
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Like you noted, you can solve this problem with a loop:

```
Dim TotalRooms = 0

For Each c In Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)
   If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(c.Text) Then TotalRooms += 1
Next

MessageBox.Show(TotalRooms)
```

Answer (score 0):

Brian's answer is perfectly fine if the only textboxes in your form are those that you want to check, But if you have other textboxes with text in them, the code will also see them as not empty and you'll get an incorrect answer.

Assuming that all your `txtRooms` textboxes follow the same naming convention, this should work ..

```
For i As Integer = 1 To 10
    Dim tempTxtBox As Control() = Controls.Find("txtRoom" & i.ToString, False)
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(DirectCast(tempTxtBox(0), TextBox).Text) Then TotalRooms += 1
Next
```

You just need to change the number 10 in the `For` statement to the number of rooms you have.

Just a small tip. If you're writing this code for multiple customers, you might be  better creating a constant at the beginning of your code so that if you have other code that acts on all the rooms, you'll just need to change the number of rooms in one place.

Comment: Thanks, i have tried it but i get this following error. System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.'

Comment: Odd. I tried it and it worked fine. What was the value of `i` at the point of the error?